# Can we get request parameters from Django settings or other variables?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I see that the request parameters can be obtained in a viewset function using request variable.
eg:

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def mysampleviewsetfunction(self, request):
     print request
```

But, I want to be able to access request from some common variable.  The purpose of that is to write a common function that can be called from all viewsets.  This common function should be able to access request parameters depending upon the viewset that called it.  But for some reason, I don't want to send the request parameter to this common function.
My code should look like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def mysampleviewsetfunction(self, request):
      commonfunction()

def commonfunction():
      print xxxx.request
```

This 'xxxx' should be some global django variable that stores the current viewset's request.  Is there any global variable that stores current viewset's request?

Comment: Why you can't put request as params to function
`def commonfunction(request):
    print request` ?

Comment: global variables that can change value will never work on an asyncronous framework. If two people go to your website at the same time, which request do you expect to use?

Comment: @KonstantinMoiseenko: The common function was implemented long back and it didn't have the need to access request parameters till now.  Now, I want to access request parameters inside the function but that would mean I have to go change all the functions that call the common function.(i.e. the common function has to be called with an extra parameter 'request').  I just thought if there's way to access request from a common variable, it'd save me the trouble of modifying all the functions.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? In a we context the request is unique to the (http) request.

Comment: @Sayse: I understand your point.  But, before calling viewset, Django must have stored request in some variable, right? This must be some variable that is unique to the context that calls the viewset. I'm just asking if there's a way to get request from that variable.

Comment: @linuxfreak - Nothing is stored globally (other than settings)

Comment: @Sayse - Thanks.  I'd like to understand how Django is implemented.  i.e. I want to understand the stages a request undergoes before being routed to a viewset.  Could you point me to some link which explains that?

Comment: @linuxfreak - [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/)  (Note: These are going to be changed slightly in 1.10 but their use case is the same)

Answer (score 1):

> it'd save me the trouble of modifying all the functions.

You wouldn't have to if you provide a default.

```
def commonfunction(request=None):
```

This of course means that any existing function calls won't be able to use the request until you update them so you'll need a check to make sure the request isn't none in this function.

There isn't any way you could use a global variable since that won't work asyncronously